# How to force a HKQuery to load the most recent steps counts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

Currently I'm trying to use `HKStatisticsQuery` to get the steps count between a certain time interval. I'm doing test by `shaking` the phone myself. However, it seems that the result I get is not the most recent one, unless:

1. I open the `Health.app`, keep it running in background, and do the test again in my app;
2. I open the `UP app`, keep it running in background, and do the test again in my app.

And if I force-quit the `Health.app` or`UP app`, my app will not be able to get the most recent data again. So UP must be doing something I'm missing, but I can't find there's any "reload" like method in `HKHealthStore`, or any related options in `HKQuery/HKStatisticsQuery`.

The code I'm using is quite straight forward as below. I wonder if there's any permissions or anything I'm missing.

```
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(date_start, endDate: NSDate(), options: HKQueryOptions.StrictStartDate)
    var type = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning)
    var query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: type,
        quantitySamplePredicate: predicate,
        options: .CumulativeSum | .SeparateBySource,
        completionHandler: { query, stats, error in ( /*logs here*/ ) })
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    healthStore.executeQuery(query)
```

Edit: I also tried to write some data to `HealthKit` but the query doesn't get updated.

Edit2: when I said "most recent steps counts" I meant something like: 1. execute HKQuery; 2. shake phone; 3. execute HKQuery again. Running the code above for 2 times and I always get the same results, but if I left Health.app or the `UP` app in the background, the latest query got the updated results.

I also tried to call some other APIs like:

```
    healthStore.enableBackgroundDeliveryForType(type, frequency:.Immediate, withCompletion:{
        (success:Bool, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        let authorized = healthStore.authorizationStatusForType(type)
        LF.log("HEALTH callback success", success)
        LF.log("HEALTH callback authorized", type)
    })

    if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() == false {
        LF.log("HEALTH data not available")
        return
    } else {
        LF.log("HEALTH OK")
    }
```

For almost no reason but try to secretly "trigger" some sort of background refresh. But none of these attempts worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

HealthKit does not always have an up-to-date count of the user's steps and distance travelled.  It imports these values, which actually come from CoreMotion.framework, periodically and in response to certain events.  If a running application has an open `HKObserverQuery` or `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` then HealthKit will stream the values to the client but otherwise the samples are just a snapshot from the last import.

So if you'd like to observe changes for a sample type, you should subscribe to updates using an `HKObserverQuery` and then query HealthKit again for the latest values.  A more efficient approach would be to use `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery`, though, which has an update handler that will be invoked as the statistics for the samples matching the predicates change.

Finally, if you're only interested up-to-date step counts or distance travelled for at most the past 7 days then I recommend that you consider using CoreMotion.framework directly instead.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. I've been calling `HKStatisticsQuery` multiple times when the view reloads (`viewWillAppear`).

Comment: Got it.  I'm going to amend my answer to be more helpful in that case.

Comment: Thanks! I think it's a bug of Apple but `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` with `statisticsUpdateHandler` did the trick.