# HealthKit not up to date

Tags: ios, healthkit

I'm using HealthKit in one of my apps

I may be using it wrong, but I have found that when reading steps (I haven't tried with other data), new step data isn't returned in my query and I need to open the Health app, and then open my app for that new information to be returned by the query.

```
if([HKHealthStore isHealthDataAvailable])
{
    HKHealthStore *healthStore = [[HKHealthStore alloc] init];

    //  Query for step data
    HKQuantityType *stepType = [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount];
    NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:@[stepType]];

    [healthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:nil readTypes:set completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

        if(success)
        {
            //  Steps in 30 minute increments
            NSDateComponents *intervalComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
            [intervalComponents setMinute:30];

            NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

            NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

            NSDate *startDate = [calendar startOfDayForDate:now];
            NSDate *endDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:1 toDate:startDate options:0];

            //  From the start of today until the end of today
            NSPredicate *datePredicate = [HKQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate options:(HKQueryOptionStrictStartDate | HKQueryOptionStrictEndDate)];

            HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query = [[HKStatisticsCollectionQuery alloc] initWithQuantityType:stepType
                                                                                   quantitySamplePredicate:datePredicate
                                                                                                   options:(HKStatisticsOptionCumulativeSum)
                                                                                                anchorDate:startDate
                                                                                        intervalComponents:intervalComponents];

            [query setInitialResultsHandler:^(HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query, HKStatisticsCollection *result, NSError *error) {

                for(HKStatistics *statistics in result.statistics)
                {
                    NSLog(@"%@, %@", @([statistics.sumQuantity doubleValueForUnit:[HKUnit countUnit]]), statistics.startDate);
                }
            }];

            [healthStore executeQuery:query];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, step data gets updated only if I open the Health app and then my App, it doesn't get updated even if I wait for longtime. Did u figure out any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the same thing too - check out the following SO answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27239738/3847

Looks like HealthKit only imports the step information from CoreMotion periodically, hence the delay you're seeing.  Adding the callback for me didn't work as it only seems to callback once the step data is imported into HealthKit