# iOS read data from HealthKit

Tags: ios, iphone, health-monitoring, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I have an app that read data from HealthKit. I can read data from it successfully. However I noticed an issue. When the Health app is not open and I try to read data from it, HealthKit just returns old data, any new data like steps that I've just taken is not returned. So I wait for about 45 minutes, then the latest data is returned. BUT when I open HealthKit app at that time (instead of waiting 45 minutes), latest data is returned. 
I'm not sure if it would take sometimes for HealthKit to return latest data to 3rd party app, or we can force HealthKit to return latest data by openning Health app.
Is this a bug?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force a HKQuery to load the most recent steps counts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223353/how-to-force-a-hkquery-to-load-the-most-recent-steps-counts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug. As far as I know, there is no way of forcing HealthKit from returning the latest data, because the data is not actually inside the Health Store yet.

Health Store receives data in batches, periodically. An Apple employee previously stated this on the developer forums (In a WatchKit thread, actually). The time he stated was "Around 15 minutes".

Comment: Thanks alot for the info. Do you know any other way to get latest data?

Comment: When I read the HealthKit framework document, I recall there being some kind of HKObserver that can monitor the health store. Might be useful to look into that.

Comment: I couldn't find it, would you please give me a link?

Comment: I was actually fiddling with that today. Spent 5 hours with no luck, but this is definitely what you want. Let me know if you manage to figure out how to use this... Basically the HKObserverQuery is able to retrieve information whenever new data gets added to HealthKit, and will even do it while your back is in the background, if you customize the closure properly. I failed to do so. Please post back if you find out!

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKObserverQuery_Class/index.html