# Receiving "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" as an error in a HealthKit HKStatisticsQuery

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm working on an app in Swift 4.0 that uses Apple's HealthKit. I have the app working getting the user's steps from HealthKit. Here is my working code:

```
//sampleType declaration
    let sampleType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)

    //define the predicate from the passed start and end times
    let queryPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: .strictStartDate)

    //build the query
    let cumulativeSumQuery = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: sampleType!, quantitySamplePredicate: queryPredicate, options: .cumulativeSum, completionHandler: { (cumulativeSumQuery, results, error ) in

        //PROCESS THE DATA//

    })

    //execute the query
    self.healthStore.execute(cumulativeSumQuery)
```

The problem is that it takes data from multiple sources. So I want to add .separateBySource as an option in my HKStatistics. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223353/how-to-force-a-hkquery-to-load-the-most-recent-steps-counts) and [the Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticsoptions), the following code *should* work by simply adding `| .separateBySource` to my `options:`

```
//sampleType declaration
    let sampleType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)

    //define the predicate from the passed start and end times
    let queryPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: .strictStartDate)

    //build the query
    let cumulativeSumQuery = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: sampleType!, quantitySamplePredicate: queryPredicate, options: .cumulativeSum | .separateBySource, completionHandler: { (cumulativeSumQuery, results, error ) in

        //PROCESS THE DATA//

    })

    //execute the query
    self.healthStore.execute(cumulativeSumQuery)
```

But instead, I get the error `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`. Xcode red underlines the `|` character in between my two options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For swift 4.0 Replace:

```
let cumulativeSumQuery = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: sampleType!, quantitySamplePredicate: queryPredicate, options: .cumulativeSum | .separateBySource, completionHandler: { (cumulativeSumQuery, results, error ) in

    //PROCESS THE DATA//

})
```

With

```
//build the query
let cumulativeSumQuery = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: sampleType!, quantitySamplePredicate: queryPredicate, options: HKStatisticsOptions(rawValue: HKStatisticsOptions.RawValue(UInt8(HKStatisticsOptions.cumulativeSum.rawValue) | UInt8(HKStatisticsOptions.separateBySource.rawValue))), completionHandler: { (cumulativeSumQuery, results, error ) in

    //PROCESS THE DATA//

})
```

For more info check this declaration:

```
 @enum          HKStatisticsOptions


 @abstract      Options for specifying which statistics to calculate
 @discussion    When querying for HKStatistics objects, an options bitmask will specify which statistics will be 
                calculated.

                Statistics are classified as discrete or cumulative.  If a discrete statistics option is specified for a
                cumulative HKQuantityType, an exception will be thrown.  If a cumulative statistics options is specified
                for a discrete HKQuantityType, an exception will also be thrown.

 @constant      HKStatisticsOptionNone
 @constant      HKStatisticsOptionSeparateBySource
 @constant      HKStatisticsOptionDiscreteAverage   Calculate averageQuantity when creating statistics.
 @constant      HKStatisticsOptionDiscreteMin       Calculate minQuantity when creating statistics.
 @constant      HKStatisticsOptionDiscreteMax       Calculate maxQuantity when creating statistics.
 @constant      HKStatisticsOptionCumulativeSum     Calculate sumQuantity when creating statistics.

@available(iOS 8.0, *)
public struct HKStatisticsOptions : OptionSet {

    public init(rawValue: UInt)


    public static var separateBySource: HKStatisticsOptions { get }

    public static var discreteAverage: HKStatisticsOptions { get }

    public static var discreteMin: HKStatisticsOptions { get }

    public static var discreteMax: HKStatisticsOptions { get }

    public static var cumulativeSum: HKStatisticsOptions { get }
}
```