# HealthKit data is not refreshed until I force close and open the app again

Tags: ios, swift, distance, healthkit

I'm trying to get the steps and distance walked from a concrete day to now, on an iOS app.
Also, I need to refresh that data continuously, real-time like.

I tried two different ways of doing that, but both are returning always the same data until I force close and open the app again.

```
private func getDataSinceDate(startDate: Date, type: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier, success: @escaping (Double) -> Void, hkUnit: HKUnit, failure: @escaping (Error?)->()) {
        
        // type = .distanceWalkingRunning
        // hkUnit = HKUnit.meter()

        let quantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: type)!
        let startDateDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: startDate)
        
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(
            withStart: startDateDay,
            end: .now,
            options: .strictEndDate
        )
        
        let query = HKStatisticsQuery(
            quantityType: quantityType,
            quantitySamplePredicate: predicate,
            options: .cumulativeSum
        ) { _, result, error in
            
            if error != nil {
                failure(error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let result = result, let sum = result.sumQuantity() else {
                success(0)
                return
            }
            
            success(sum.doubleValue(for: hkUnit))
        }
        
        healthStore.execute(query)
    }
```

also tried

```
func getDistance(start: Date, end: Date, completion: ((Double)->())?) {

        let timePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: start), end: end, options: .strictStartDate)

            let walkingCompound = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
            [timePredicate])

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)
        
        var sum : Double = 0.0
        
        let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning)!, predicate: walkingCompound, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, samples, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            for case let inSample as HKQuantitySample in samples ?? [] {
                sum += inSample.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.meter())
            }
            
            completion?(sum)
        }
        
        healthStore.execute(query)
    }
```

Both with the same problem. They're not refreshing the data.
I would like to get the steps / distance collected on HealthKit (steps/distance also on Apple Watch) but I don't want to do a Watch app because I don't want to depend on Apple Watch to do this, as there are many people using other smart bands.

Is there any way to have updated data every time I request it?

Comment: HealthKit does update periodically and is not allways up to date. For more look at this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/27239738/6950415. May be old but still relevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force a HKQuery to load the most recent steps counts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223353/how-to-force-a-hkquery-to-load-the-most-recent-steps-counts)

Comment: This doesn't work to me neither. I have to FINISH a workout or close/open the app for retrieving data refreshed. Until then, I got always the same data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `end` predicate is not refreshing to `now` each time you run your query. You can use `nil` as `end` to get all data since your starting date or double-check if your `end` is refreshing to `now`.

For getting real-time data, you can set a `HKObserverQuery` to get notified every time HealthKit gets new Steps data, and run your `HKStatisticsQuery` inside the ObserverQuery's handler.

Another option for you is using a `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` instead of your `HKStatisticsQuery`, as in `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` you can set an update handler that updates your statistics each time HK gets new data. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticscollectionquery/1615723-statisticsupdatehandler

Comment: Yes, but in those cases, as you said, you get updates when "HK gets data" and that's not in real time. You can test it by for example doing a running exercise. And the values are not updated until you finish the exercise. I would like to get the info while you're running.